# Plot of x,y coordinates with their respective u,v directions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, numpy, data-visualization

I'm trying to visualize a data from a CSV file. The data in the file has x, y, z, u, v, w coordinates. The z and w coordinate are always zero, hence need not to be plotted.

I'm trying to read the columns and store them in a list and later trying to plot it in a 2D graph.

The data in the .csv file looks like the following(it is already separated in columns) and there are approx 6000 lines in the file:

> x     y           z     u       v         w
>
> 0.00E+00, 0.00E+00, 0, 0.00E+00, 0.00E+00, 0
>
> 0.00E+00, 1.88E-03, 0, 0.00E+00, 0.00E+00, 0
>
> 0.00E+00, 5.78E-03, 0, 0.00E+00, 0.00E+00, 0
>
> 0.00E+00, 9.95E-03, 0, 0.00E+00, 0.00E+00, 0
>
> 0.00E+00, 1.44E-02, 0, 0.00E+00, 0.00E+00, 0

I'm new in data visualization and trying to do some simulation. Any help would be very helpful.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv
import pandas

colnames = {'x', 'y', 'z', 'u', 'v', 'w'}
data = pandas.read_csv('field2.csv', names=colnames)

xp = data.x.tolist()
yp = data.y.tolist()
up = data.u.tolist()
wp = data.w.tolist()

plt.plot(xp,yp,up,wp, label='plot!')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It seems that you are looking for [quiver plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html). Use plt.quiver instead.

Comment: @bubble I tired to use quiver plot but it gives me errors.  Before I used plt.plot(), I tried with plt.quiver() and passed the same parameters.

Comment: Can we pass values of the list as parameters in quiver()? @bubble

Comment: I think, quiver will work with 1D lists too; But, why do you need lists: you already have numpy arrays, e.g. `data.x.values` is a numpy array. They are usually more convenient...